# Remove characters by position from string

Tags: swift

I want to remove two characters by position from string, form example I want to remove character from `subCadenaTX4` at position 4 and 5

```
let fechaNacRFC = "25/12/1997"
let subCadenaTX4 = fechaNacRFC!.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
print(subCadenaTX4) // It will be 25121997
```

I read that I can use `removeAtIndex` but what it is the way in this case?

My expected output: `251297`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: var nonempty = "non-empty"
if let i = nonempty.firstIndex(of: "-") {
    nonempty.remove(at: i)
}
print(nonempty)
// Prints "nonempty"

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica  My expected output: 251297

Comment: let fechaNacRFC = "25/12/1997"
let subCadenaTX4 = fechaNacRFC!.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
print(subCadenaTX4)                                                                                             var nonempty = subCadenaTX4  if let i = nonempty.firstIndex(of: "19") { nonempty.remove(at: i) } print(nonempty) // Prints "nonempty"

Comment: I think you're making a mistake by having a string in your program represent a date. You should represent a date using... `Date`. If `"25/12/1997"` is an input you get from some external system (e.g. a network request), you should parse it as it comes in, into a `Date`. If `25121997` is something you need to send out to interface with an external system, you should use a `DateFormatter` to convert it from a `Date` to a `String` *at the last possible place, at the boundary*. Within your app, you should always strive to use the right data types to make handling data easier.

Comment: Please, always use 4 digits to represent a year. Otherwise you will have a Y2K problem sooner or later.

Comment: @Sulthan I agree but I need that format  for ID that mexicans use (RFC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just build a new string using `prefix` and `suffix` or `dropFirst`:

```
let subCadenaTX4 = "25121997"

// Desire: drop characters at position 4 and 5
// use prefix to get the first 4 characters
// use suffix to get the last 2 characters
// call String() to covert the result back to String
let result = String(subCadenaTX4.prefix(4) + subCadenaTX4.suffix(2))
```

**or:**

```
// Desire: drop characters at position 4 and 5
// use prefix to get the first 4 characters
// Use dropFirst(6) to pick string starting at position 6
// call String to convert result to String
let result = String(subCadenaTX4.prefix(4) + subCadenaTX4.dropFirst(6))
```

Comment: This answer directly answered what your were asking and could be helpful in other situations where you want to leave out part of a string, but [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62561419/1630618) is definitely the way to go when dealing with dates.

Answer (score 5):

I think this code is much more clearly expressed by making the intent more clear, rather than mucking about with string indices.

This also gives you a natural way to validate that the input is in a valid format.

```
import Foundation

// You can cache and reuse these 
let parser = DateFormatter()
parser.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyy"


let input = "25/12/1997"
guard let date = parser.date(from: input) else {
    // TODO: handle error here properly.
    fatalError("The input wasn't in the expected format!")
}
let output = formatter.string(from: date)

print(output) // => 251297
```

Imagine if the date source changed its format, say to ISO 8601, feeding your system `"1997-12-25"`. Suppose you implement your trasnformation as you're trying to do, by first replacing `"/"` with `""`, and then removing the 4th and 5th characters. Your system will just silently accept this invalid input, and quietly spit out `"19972-25"`, with no indication that an error occurred.

With this approach, the input format is trivially validated, and you'll catch non-sense like this with a loud error, rather than silently wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeSubrange`:

```
let index1 = subCadenaTX4.index(subCadenaTX4.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let index2 = subCadenaTX4.index(index1, offsetBy: 1)
subCadenaTX4.removeSubrange(index1...index2)
print(subCadenaTX4) // prints 251297
```